# OpenGLESv2 Shader glGetAttribLocation returns -1

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Hey, I try to code a OpenGL ES 2 engine but at shader creation the function glGetAttribLocation returns -1 which means

> The named attribute variable is not an
>   active    attribute in the specified
>   program object or the name starts with
>   the reserved prefix   "gl_".

But it IS defined in the shader and doesnt start with gl_.
Whats wrong with my code?

C++ Code:

```
glprogram = glCreateProgram();

glvertshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glfragshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

glShaderSource(glvertshader, 1, vertsrc, NULL);
glShaderSource(glfragshader, 1, fragsrc, NULL);

GLint ret;

glCompileShader(glvertshader);
glGetShaderiv(glvertshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &ret);
if(!ret)
{
    ///error handling - stripped for the internet
}

glCompileShader(glfragshader);
glGetShaderiv(glfragshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &ret);
if(!ret)
{
    ///error handling - stripped for the internet
}

glAttachShader(glprogram, glvertshader);
glAttachShader(glprogram, glfragshader);

glLinkProgram(glprogram);

glGetProgramiv(glprogram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &ret);
if(!ret)
{
    ///error handling - stripped for the internet
}

glattributes[0] = glGetAttribLocation(glprogram, "vertex");
glattributes[1] = glGetAttribLocation(glprogram, "texcoord_vs");



std::cout << "texcoord " << glGetAttribLocation(glprogram, "texcoord_vs";
```

Vert shader:

```
// Vertex Shader for OpenGL ES
uniform mat4 projmat;
uniform mat4 modviewmat;

attribute vec2 vertex;
attribute vec2 texcoord_vs;

varying vec2 texcoord_fs;

void main()
{
    texcoord_fs = texcoord_vs;
    gl_Position = projmat*modviewmat*vec4(vertex, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

edit: correct shader code and the error is with texcoord_vs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify which attribute is not used, but I assume it's "texcoord_vs", simply because you're not using it, and as such it's being stripped by the shader compiler.

I suppose you meant to say `texcoord_fs = texcoord_vs`?

Comment: yes, it is texcoord_vs and I fixed the error with vertex and texcoord_vs now but the error is still the same :(

Comment: Does your fragment shader use texcoord_fs?

Comment: atm, i commented the use but THAT was it..didnt think the compiler was using that optimization.

thank you really really much ;)

Comment: Does your fragment shader actually use the texcoord_fs value you're passing to it? If not, then texcoord_vs may still be getting optimized away as it is effectively unused.

Comment: Yes, the compiler keeps track of what's used and strips out anything that ends up being unused, which is good because you can't afford any waste in a shader. Btw, please accept this answer with the checkmark if your problem is solved. Thanks!